# Any way to convert `sp_consensus_babe::app::Public` to `T::AccountId`?

Tags: pallet

I am trying to get the block author via `find_author` with digest. I can get the `authority_id` whose type is `sp_consensus_babe::app::Public` or `sp_consensus_aura::app::Public`, how can I convert this to validator's AccountId?

What I want to do is:

```
pub struct FindAuthorTruncated<T, F>(PhantomData<(T, F)>);
impl<T: Config, F: FindAuthor<u32>> FindAuthor<H160> for FindAuthorTruncated<T, F> {
    fn find_author<'a, I>(digests: I) -> Option<H160>
    where
        I: 'a + IntoIterator<Item = (ConsensusEngineId, &'a [u8])>,
    {
        F::find_author(digests).map(|author_index| {
            let authority_id = Aura::authorities()[author_index as usize].clone();

            // Is there any way to convert the authority_id to T::AccountId?

            H160::from_slice(&authority_id.to_raw_vec()[4..24])
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using the session pallet, then you should use `pallet_session::FindAccountFromAuthorIndex`. If you are not using the session pallet then it depends on what you are using to manage the validator set. E.g. in the node-template runtime there is no pallet to manage the validator set and instead the authorities are an hard-coded list in the aura pallet.

Comment: Using `pallet_session::FindAccountFromAuthorIndex;` is much easier way if Babe and session pallet installed. However, I am not sure If this way works with Aura? I checked the substrate node template runtime https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/main/runtime/src/lib.rs#L275. It seems no session pallet needed if enable Aura pallet? If so, this way might not works, since we no session pallet.

Comment: Or are there any examples using Aura together with the session pallet?

Comment: Good point, I did not remember about `pallet_session::FindAccountFromAuthorIndex`, I will edit my answer. The solution will be specific to your runtime, if you use the session module then you want to use that in order to get the validator ID from the session (since aura/babe will only know session keys). The node template does not use the session module and instead the validators are a static list in the aura module.

Answer (score 0):

A not so perfect solution is:

```
let account_id = T::AccountId::decode(&mut authority_id.0.as_slice()).unwrap();
```

Comment: This works but is not correct in most cases (i.e. if you use the session module).